# How to achieve CSS customization in a CSS concatenation build process

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, gulp

The modern code structure and build process like gulp-angular concatenates all css to a single file, and we include that in a web page.

Let's say I have a template.html, and I want to show different styles each day of the week. So I have monday.css, tuesday.css, ..., sunday.css.

If monday.css, tuesday.css, ..., sunday.css are all stitched together, I can't achieve customization...

What is the best way to have the build process include the particular css respective to the day of the week?

[Updated] I found this project https://github.com/door3/angular-css On the face of it, it seems to be what I am looking for. Has anyone used it in a build environment like gulp-angular where they concatenate and minify all the css files?

Comment: the easiest way is to add a different class to body or html each day, from there , one style sheet is no problem and can be loaded by your visitors

Comment: Are you saying doing something like <body class="monday"> and then load monday.css?  But monday.css...sunday.css are already loaded

Comment: no i mean :  body.monday #idwhatever {color: blue}  body.tuesday #idwhatever {color:red} .  this class or id on body becomes like a filter and they can be all together in the sheet. you only need to write what is different from a day to another

Comment: I see. This might work in simple cases: if all my monday.css...sunday.css have only simple .idwhatever {...}.  If my monday.css has something like div:nth-child(2n) {...}, and my tuesday.css has div:nth-child(3n) {..}, etc. Will this approach still work?  I was more thinking of dynamically loading the respective [day of the week].css...

Comment: Yes, it will work. @GCyrillus' method is the way to go. You can make it a little less painful by using something like LESS, so you can nest your styles. So everything that goes on Mondays goes inside a giant .monday { ... } wrapper.

Comment: @GormCasper and GCyrillus  Just to make sure I get the idea right.  So in my template.html, I dynamically inject the day of week as my class in the root/parent div: <div class="monday">...</div>.  And then in my monday.css, I use .monday as the root and style everything within it?